# Reference credential in CMD called by DSC

Tags: t-sql, powershell, dsc

I was wondering how I can reference credential in CMD called by DSC.
This is the configuration that I'm trying to deploy, but it doesn't receive credentials.

```
configuration SQLCMD
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [PSCredential]
        $Credential

    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xSqlServer

    Node localhost
    {

        LocalConfigurationManager
        {
            ConfigurationMode = 'ApplyOnly'
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
            ActionAfterReboot = 'ContinueConfiguration'
            AllowModuleOverwrite = $true
        }

        Script DeployDBmoveTempDB 
        { 
            SetScript = { 
$SourceFile = 'C:\DatabaseTest.dacpac'
$TargetServerName = 'localhost'
$TargetDatabaseName = 'TestDB1'
$databaseSizeSQLCMD = '200MB'
$databaseLogSizeSQLCMD = '20MB'
$tempdbSizeSQLCMD = '1900MB'
$tempdbLogSizeSQLCMD = '1900MB'


trap {
    Write-Error $_
    Exit 1
}

 $args = @('/Action:Publish'
             ,"/SourceFile:$SourceFile"
             ,"/TargetServerName:$TargetServerName"
             ,"/TargetUser:$Credential.UserName"
             ,"/TargetPassword:$Credential"
             ,"/TargetDatabaseName:$TargetDatabaseName"
             ,"/v:databaseSizeSQLCMD=$databaseSizeSQLCMD"
             ,"/v:databaseLogSizeSQLCMD=$databaseLogSizeSQLCMD"
             ,"/v:tempdbSizeSQLCMD=$databaseSizeSQLCMD"
             ,"/v:tempdbLogSizeSQLCMD=$databaseLogSizeSQLCMD"
             ,'/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false'
             )            

    try {
        & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" $args


    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $_ ;
    }   

        } 

            TestScript = { 
            Test-Path D:\TestDB1_primary.mdf
        } 
            GetScript = { <# This must return a hash table #> }
        }

    }
}
```

However, the following configuration works fine:

```
configuration SQLCMD
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [PSCredential]
        $Credential

    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xSqlServer

    Node localhost
    {

        LocalConfigurationManager
        {
            ConfigurationMode = 'ApplyOnly'
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
            ActionAfterReboot = 'ContinueConfiguration'
            AllowModuleOverwrite = $true
        }

        Script DeployDBmoveTempDB 
        { 
            SetScript = { 
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$SourceFile = 'C:\DatabaseTest.dacpac'
$TargetServerName = 'localhost'
$user_name = 'mySqlAdmin'
$user_pwd = 'blabla'
$TargetDatabaseName = 'TestDB1'
$databaseSizeSQLCMD = '200MB'
$databaseLogSizeSQLCMD = '20MB'
$tempdbSizeSQLCMD = '1900MB'
$tempdbLogSizeSQLCMD = '1900MB'


trap {
    Write-Error $_
    Exit 1
}

 $args = @('/Action:Publish'
             ,"/SourceFile:$SourceFile"
             ,"/TargetServerName:$TargetServerName"
             ,"/TargetUser:$user_name"
             ,"/TargetPassword:$user_pwd"
             ,"/TargetDatabaseName:$TargetDatabaseName"
             ,"/v:databaseSizeSQLCMD=$databaseSizeSQLCMD"
             ,"/v:databaseLogSizeSQLCMD=$databaseLogSizeSQLCMD"
             ,"/v:tempdbSizeSQLCMD=$databaseSizeSQLCMD"
             ,"/v:tempdbLogSizeSQLCMD=$databaseLogSizeSQLCMD"
             ,'/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false'
             )            

    try {
        & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" $args


    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $_ ;
    }   

        } 

            TestScript = { 
            Test-Path D:\TestDB1_primary.mdf
        } 
            GetScript = { <# This must return a hash table #> }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/xDatabase ?

Comment: You can't pass credentials to external commands like that. Not only don't external command know anything about PowerShell objects in the first place, but `$Credential` in a string is expanded to the string representation of a credential object, which is the string `"System.Management.Automation.PSCredential"`. You need to expand the username and password from your credential object and pass that to the external command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSC-configurations store scripts as strings in the generated mof and does not expand variables by default since it wouldn't know which to expand and which to keep as part of the script. However, by specifying the `$using:`-Scope, you can include variables defined in the configuration. During mof-compilcation, the variables are then added at the start of each of the Get-/Set-/TestScript scriptblocks.
Ex:

```
configuration SQLCMD
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [PSCredential]
        $Credential    
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xSqlServer

    $user_name = $Credential.UserName
    $user_pwd = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

    Node localhost
    {    
        Script DeployDBmoveTempDB 
        { 
            SetScript = { 

                $TargetDatabaseName = 'TestDB1'
                $args = @(,"/TargetUser:$using:user_name"
                             ,"/TargetPassword:$using:user_pwd"
                             ,"/TargetDatabaseName:$TargetDatabaseName")                
                try {
                    & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" $args
                }
                catch { Write-Host $_  }       
            }     
            TestScript = { Test-Path "D:\TestDB1_primary.mdf" }             
            GetScript = { <# This must return a hash table #> }
        }

    }
}
```

**Be aware that the password will be stored in plain text in the mof-file.** Ex:

```
SetScript = "$user_name ='User1'\n$user_pwd ='Password1'\n \n\n                $TargetDatabaseName = 'TestDB1'\n                $args = @(,\"/TargetUser:$user_name\"\n                       
      ,\"/TargetPassword:$user_pwd\"\n                             ,\"/TargetDatabaseName:$TargetDatabaseName\")            \n\n                try {\n                    & \"C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DAC\\bin\\SqlPackage.exe\" $args\n                }\n                catch { Write-Host $_  }   \n\n            ";
```

Comment: Unfortunately with these lines I get this error `[ERROR] PowerShell DSC resource 
MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with 
error message: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. `

Comment: See update. And remember to pass a credential to `SQLCMD` when compiling the configuration

Comment: Updated answer. Found a better way (using-scope vs string replacement) to access common variables/parameters.